# Conditional construction of environment

Tags: environments, conditionals

The following codes try to build `starting code` `ending code` of an `environment` *with condition*.

For example:
if the value of `#1` is 1, the starting code of the environment `test` is:

```
\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
```

the ending code is:

```
\end{minipage}
CASE 1
some other things after test content
\end{minipage}
```

and so on. That is to say, both "starting code" and "ending code" would be changed according to the value of #1.

And, it does not work. What's wrong with the codes?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\newenvironment{test}[1]
    {
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    \ifcase#1
    \or
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    }
    {
    \end{minipage}
    CASE 1
    \or
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    }
    {
    \end{minipage}
    CASE 2
    \or
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    }
    {
    \end{minipage}
    CASE 3    
    \fi
    some other things after test content
    \end{minipage}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{test}{1}
\begin{lstlisting}
some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

**Edited:**

```
\newenvironment{test}[1]
    {%
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    \ifcase#1
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \fi    
    }
    {%
    \end{minipage}
    \ifcase#1
    \or case 1
    \or case 2
    \or case 3
    \fi
    some other things after test content
    \end{minipage}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you show initially is full of syntax errors. You ***cannot*** have `\ifcase` starting in the “begin part” and ending in the “end part”, because TeX skips tokens for the “false branches” without interpreting them, so it will almost never expand `\end{test}`.

The code you show later doesn't work for a different reason: `#1` is ***not*** allowed in the trailing argument to `\newenvironment` and has never been since LaTeX was first released.

Why? Probably because Leslie Lamport didn't know how to do it or didn't feel the urge for allowing parameters in the “end part”.

How's that “classically” worked around? Simple.

```
\newenvironment{test}[1]
   {%
    \def\argumentfortest{#1}%
    \par\noindent
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    \ifcase#1\relax
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \fi    
   }
   {%
    \end{minipage}%
    \ifcase\argumentfortest\relax
    \or case 1 %
    \or case 2 %
    \or case 3 %
    \fi
    some other things after test content%
    \end{minipage}%
   }
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{test}[1]
   {%
    \def\argumentfortest{#1}%
    \par\noindent
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    \ifcase#1\relax
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \fi    
   }
   {%
    \end{minipage}%
    \ifcase\argumentfortest\relax
    \or case 1 %
    \or case 2 %
    \or case 3 %
    \fi
    some other things after test content%
    \end{minipage}%
   }

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Argument is 1}

\begin{test}{1}
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X
\end{test}

\subsubsection*{Argument is 3}

\begin{test}{2}
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X
\end{test}

\subsubsection*{Argument is 3}

\begin{test}{3}
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, parameters *can* be used in the “end part”.

```
\errorcontextlines=10000
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{m}
  {
    \par\noindent
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    \begin{minipage}{\lyl_test_factor:n { #1 }\textwidth}
  }
  {
    \end{minipage}
    \lyl_test_post:n { #1 }~some~other~things~after~test~content
    \end{minipage}
  }

\cs_new:Nn \lyl_test_factor:n
  {
    \int_case:nn { #1 } { {1}{0.4} {2}{0.5} {3}{0.6} }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \lyl_test_post:n
  {
    \int_case:nn { #1 }
      {
        {1}{case~1}
        {2}{case~2}
        {3}{case~3}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Argument is 1}

\begin{test}{1}
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X
\end{test}

\subsubsection*{Argument is 3}

\begin{test}{2}
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X
\end{test}

\subsubsection*{Argument is 3}

\begin{test}{3}
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X\par
X\dotfill X
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

When TeX sees and expands `\ifcase` in `\begin{test}`, the `\fi` is hidden in `\end{test}`, hence the `\ifcase ... \or ... \fi` is incomplete and causes errors.

Thus you have to construct a complete `\ifcase ... \or ... \fi` at both begin and end of an environment. To have access to environment argument at the end of an env, `\NewDocumentEnvironment` is one of the capable choices.

> You cannot use `#1` in the end part with `\newenvironment`. 
> --- @egreg in [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650003/conditional-construction-of-environment/650008?noredirect=1#comment1619965_650008)

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{ m }{
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    \ifcase#1
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \or\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
    \fi
}{
    \end{minipage}
    CASE #1
    \ifcase #1
    \or first case
    \or second case
    \or third case
    \fi
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{test}{1}
\begin{lstlisting}
some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{test}

\begin{test}{2}
\begin{lstlisting}
some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{test}

\begin{test}{3}
\begin{lstlisting}
some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know why you gave five mandatory arguments to `\newenvironement`, while it only accepts three (envname, begin code, and end code). There might be some fundamental misunderstanding about at least one of `\ifxxx` conditionals, arguments, grouping, or `\newenvironment`.

Comment: `\newenvironment{test}[1]` in my code. Why `five mandatory arguments to \newenvironement`?

Comment: Why does my edited version still not work?

Comment: @lyl You cannot use `#1` in the end part with `\newenvironment`.

Comment: Why dees `LaTeX` have such a limit that '#1"  cannot be used in the `end part` with `\newenvironment`?

Comment: @lyl Because it has been so for the last 40 years.